# restoration of backup from non azure SQL database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, backup

We have database  on Azure which we have successfully replicated schema from our previous server. Now we want to restore data over it. script is too long we cant run it in console or either in management studio further in our console we dint find any option for restoring database backups by uploading dump files.

Comment: assuming you're talking about the azure sql database. tagging the correct product is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not restore a BAK (database backup) from SQL Server into Azure SQL DB singletons.  You can do this into Azure SQL DB Managed Instance, however.  There's not a lot of point of replicating your schema logically from SQL Server only to replace the database from a backup.  Please note that "dump files" are actually something different - those usually refer to Watson dumps if there is a crash in the SQL process.  This contains the memory state of the program when it crashed to aid in debugging.  I assume you meant "binary backup" (aka BAK files).

You can read about the SQL MI restore option here: [docs page for SQL MI BAK restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore)

Answer (score 0):

If you already replicated (migrated) the schema of the database from a SQL Server instance to an Azure SQL Database then you can use [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) (DMA) to migrate the data or you can use [Azure Data Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-azure-sql-online) (DMS).

DMA is free and allows only offline migrations, and that means downtime for applications. DMA can take 12 hours to migrate a 300 GB database.

The same database can be migrated on less than 2 hours using DMS, and the DMS allows for online and offline migrations but is not free. DMS allows for data validation after migration while DMA does not have that feature.

Please consider migrating again the schema of the database using DMA although migrating the schema of the database may take longer time than migrating the data using this tool. However, in my experience DMA does the best job, technically speaking, migrating a database schema.